# Как передавать данные между методами в Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Имеется вот такой код:

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include <QtCore>
#include <QFileDialog>

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget* parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::doTask(int& number, QString& ip, int& pt)
{
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QNetworkReply* reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());

    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl(ui->url->text()));
    reply = manager.get(request);

    QEventLoop loop;
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    loop.exec();

    QString source;
    source.append(QString::fromLocal8Bit(reply->readAll()));

    if (source.contains(ui->search->text(), Qt::CaseInsensitive))
    {
        qDebug() << "Okay.";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << ">>> BAD <<<";
    }

    qDebug() << "TaskID: " << number;
    qDebug() << "IP: " << ip;
    qDebug() << "Port: " << pt;
    qDebug() << "MS: " << ui->wait->value();
    QThread::currentThread()->msleep(ui->wait->value());
    qDebug() << "Processing " << " - "" of thread: " << QThread::currentThreadId();
    qDebug() << "Stopped ";
}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QVector<int> vector;
    for (int i = 0; i < ui->spinBox->value(); i++)
    {
        vector.append(i);
    }

    QProgressDialog pdialog("", "", 0, 100, this, Qt::Dialog | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
    pdialog.setLabelText("Processing..");
    pdialog.setCancelButtonText("Stop");

    QFutureWatcher<void> watcher;

    connect(&pdialog,SIGNAL(canceled()), &watcher,SLOT(cancel()));
    connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), &pdialog, SLOT(reset()));
    connect(&watcher,SIGNAL(progressRangeChanged(int,int)), &pdialog,SLOT(setRange(int,int)));
    connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(progressValueChanged(int)), &pdialog,SLOT(setValue(int)));

    QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount(ui->spinBox_2->value());

    QString ip;
    int pt;
    auto q_future = QtConcurrent::map(vector, [this, &ip, &pt](int& number)
                                      {
                                          ip = "127.0.0.1";
                                          pt = 80;
                                          doTask(number, ip, pt);
                                      });

    watcher.setFuture(q_future);

    pdialog.exec();
    watcher.waitForFinished();

    if (watcher.isCanceled())
    {
        qDebug() << "canceled!!!";
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Canceled", "You clicked cancel!");
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "finished!!!";
        QMessageBox::information(this, "finished", "All done!");
    }
}

void Dialog::on_proxy_clicked()
{
    auto proxy = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(nullptr,
                                              QObject::tr("Add proxy"),
                                              QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath(),
                                              QObject::tr("Text file (*.txt)"));

    if (true == proxy.isEmpty())
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(nullptr, "Warning", "Empty path proxy list.");
        return; // Ð¿ÐµÑ€ÐµÐ´ÑƒÐ¼Ð°Ð»Ð¸
    }
    QFile file(proxy);

    QString n;
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
        n = QTextStream(&file).readAll();

    QRegExp rx("[\:\;]");
    QRegExp rx2("[\r\n]");

    QString str(n);

    QList<QStringList> result;
    foreach(const QString &lst1, str.split(rx2, QString::SkipEmptyParts))
        result << lst1.split(rx);

    ui->cproxy->setNum(result.count());
}
```

но не совсем ясно как передать данные из `result` (`on_proxy_clicked()`) в метод `on_pushButton_clicked` для дальнейшей обработки (перебор `ip` и `port` (pt) )

Какое решение посоветуете в коде?

P.S. Просто прокси чекер.

Comment: Вставляйте код прямо в сообщение, а не ссылайтесь на внешние ресурсы. Сообщения должны быть самодостаточными, ссылки могут служить только дополнением.

Comment: @Athari я понял.

Comment: Хм. А в чём специфика именно Qt? Для обмена данными между потоками используется, например, очередь заданий. Ну или высокоуровневые примитивы синхронизации, которые маршаллируют данные за вас.

Comment: @VladD, в нем  - сигналы, слоты.

Comment: Почему бы просто не создать приватное поле в классе Dialog с тем же списком result, зполнять его в on_proxy_clicked() и читать в on_pushButton_clicked()? Из result данные очевидно будут браться до использования конкурента. В чём подвох?

Comment: @alexis031182, в моей наивности

Comment: @alexis031182, есть соображения как перебирать `result[id][1]` в конкуренте?

Comment: Если ресурс (result) разделяем между потоками, то очевидно, что нужен мьютекс. Но это опять же, если этот result планируется изменять. Если просто чтение, то и читайте без всяких мьютексов. Если result скрыт в private секции класса, то сделайте константный публичный геттер, например, по индексу или даже целиком возврат ссылки на весь список. "this" вы и так в лямбду передаёте. А больше вроде и нечего добавить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, можно слот `on_pushButton_clicked()` дополнить аргументом, имеющим значение по умолчанию. Получится что-то вроде такого в объявлении:

```
void on_pushButton_clicked(const QList<QStringList> &result = QList<QStringList>());
```

... и

```
void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked(const QList<QStringList> &result) {...}
```

... в реализации.

Таким образом, сохраняется возможность вызывать слот по кнопке, а также появляется средство передачи в него списка данных.